# How to convert a array or list to JSON?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting the data in the below format, in the post request:

```
[data={"vehicle":"rti","action_time":"2015-04-21"}]
```

I want to change it in the JSON format, so that I can get the value from request.DATA, in current case am getting error like :

(JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded)

It can be done by changing the format like:

```
{"data":{"vehicle":"rti","action_time":"2015-04-21"}}
```

but I don't want to change the post data format.

Comment: Is `data={"vehicle":"rti","action_time":"2015-04-21"}` a string by any chance?

Comment: it is coming in the same format I described above. @konart

Answer (score -1):

You can use `json.dumps(<object>)` to convert it to JSON format.

Comment: me too would like to know  :)

Comment: `json.dumps` should take an object, correctly formatted. `[data="something"]` will raise an error. Unless OP wanted to say that `{a:b}` is a list elements and `data=` is just his way to say that.